# Hiera lookup through wild cards /or regex

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a question about puppet/hiera but before that I want to give a little bit of background about our infrastructure. Currently we have some file/registry resources which we are using to manage registry or file system on our azure virtual machines. In a resource group we may have one or many virtual machines. The naming convention of the virtual machines in a resource group is following DCC-123456-01A,....-02A etc. In hiera we have information as shown below.

```
- name:  "Root file system Customer Specific"
    path: "customer/%{trusted.certname}/file_system.json"

  - name: "hotfixes customer specific"
    path: "customer/%{trusted.certname}/hotfixes.json"

  - name: "Customer Specific Registry Keys"
    path: "customer/%{trusted.certname}/registry.json"
```

[image]

As you can see we have created customer specific .json files .I don't want to create multiple folders for each virtual machine in a resource group as I have done for couple of my in customer-specific folders instead if there is somehow a wild card or regex I can use in hiera and make only one entry.

Answer (score 1):

Hiera supports globs for file paths. They are documented at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/hiera_config_yaml_5.html#specifying_file_paths.

With a glob, you should be able to do something like

```
- name: "customer specific files"
  glob: "customer/%{trusted.certname}/*.json"
```

Comment: An issue that one may encounter using glob, is the fact that you can't control the overwrite. For example, if  you have `a.json` and `b.json`, most probably will be overwritten based on their load (which is not guaranteed to be alphabetically). So if you have the data `x: y1` and `x:y2` in both hieradata, you can identify the order of load using `lookup`, but after a major upgrade (or other case) is not guaranteed the order of the load of the hiera files.